# UNIX ksh Programming

Tags: ksh

I have a | delimited file with 132 fields in every record, what I need to do is append the last 2 bytes in field 3 to field 1 than print the entire record:

example of the input record

```
field1  field2  field3   field4 field5 .... field 132
123456  xyz     01/28/99 xyz123 xyz145 .... xyz567
```

the output should be:

```
field1   field2  field3   field4 field5 .... field 132
12345699 xyz     01/28/99 xya123 xyz145 .... xyz567
```

Here's the script that I have:

```
#!/bin/ksh
IFS="|"
while read a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 a10 a11; do
    yy=`expr substr "$a3" 7 2`
    acyy=$a1$yy
    print $acyy $a2 $a3 $a4 $a5 $a6 $a7 $a8 $a9 $a10 $a11
done < infile.txt  > outfile.txt
```

is there a way to read and print all remaining fileds?

Please help and thank you

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? (It looks right to me). Show us some sample output that illustrates the problem.

Answer (score 2):

aren't 'leftover' words all assigned to the last parameter to read? (including separator, |)
if you don't want the separators just 'sed' the last param - e.g., $(echo "$a11" | sed 's/|/ /')